# Replicate self join method SQL on Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Problem: Trying to produce this table by using Pandas to replicate self join method in SQL. The objective is just to produce pair of movie_title where the length are the same.

```
        Original table                        Ouput

    Movie_title       Length              Movie_title       movie_title       Length 
    Chamber Italian   117                 Chamber Italian  Daddy Pittsburgh    117
    Grosse Wonderful  120                 Chamber Italian  Daisy Menagerie     117
    Airport Pollock   98         ===>     Grosse Wonderful Curtain Videotape   120
    Curtain Videotape 120
    Cyclone Family    113
    Daddy Pittsburgh  117
    Daisy Menagerie   117
```

SQL to produce desired output

```sql
SELECT
    x.title,
    y.title,
    x.length
FROM
    film x
INNER JOIN
    film y ON (x.length=y.length) AND (x.title != y.title)
```

I can solve for self join problem with same id(employee & manager) but this is wrinkling my brain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
new_df = df.merge(df, on='Length')
m = pd.DataFrame(np.sort(new_df.filter(like='Movie_title_'), axis=1),
                 index=new_df.index).duplicated()
new_df = new_df.loc[m, ['Movie_title_x', 'Movie_title_y', 'Length']]
```

`new_df`:

```
        Movie_title_x     Movie_title_y  Length
3    Daddy Pittsburgh   Chamber Italian     117
6     Daisy Menagerie   Chamber Italian     117
7     Daisy Menagerie  Daddy Pittsburgh     117
11  Curtain Videotape  Grosse Wonderful     120
```

---

Explaination:

The self-join part is pretty straight-forward. It's the removal of duplicates that is more complicated in `pandas`

Use [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html#pandas-dataframe-merge):

```
new_df = df.merge(df, on='Length')
```

```
        Movie_title_x  Length      Movie_title_y
0     Chamber Italian     117    Chamber Italian
1     Chamber Italian     117   Daddy Pittsburgh
2     Chamber Italian     117    Daisy Menagerie
3    Daddy Pittsburgh     117    Chamber Italian
4    Daddy Pittsburgh     117   Daddy Pittsburgh
5    Daddy Pittsburgh     117    Daisy Menagerie
6     Daisy Menagerie     117    Chamber Italian
7     Daisy Menagerie     117   Daddy Pittsburgh
8     Daisy Menagerie     117    Daisy Menagerie
9    Grosse Wonderful     120   Grosse Wonderful
10   Grosse Wonderful     120  Curtain Videotape
11  Curtain Videotape     120   Grosse Wonderful
12  Curtain Videotape     120  Curtain Videotape
13    Airport Pollock      98    Airport Pollock
14     Cyclone Family     113     Cyclone Family
```

To locate symmetric duplicates, one option is to use [`np.sort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html#numpy-sort) to order alphabetically across rows, then find [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html#pandas-dataframe-duplicated) rows:

```
t = pd.DataFrame(np.sort(new_df.filter(like='Movie_title_'), axis=1),
                 index=new_df.index)
t['duplicated'] = t.duplicated()
```

`t` (duplicated column added for display purposes only):

```
                    0                  1  duplicated
0     Chamber Italian    Chamber Italian       False
1     Chamber Italian   Daddy Pittsburgh       False
2     Chamber Italian    Daisy Menagerie       False
3     Chamber Italian   Daddy Pittsburgh        True
4    Daddy Pittsburgh   Daddy Pittsburgh       False
5    Daddy Pittsburgh    Daisy Menagerie       False
6     Chamber Italian    Daisy Menagerie        True
7    Daddy Pittsburgh    Daisy Menagerie        True
8     Daisy Menagerie    Daisy Menagerie       False
9    Grosse Wonderful   Grosse Wonderful       False
10  Curtain Videotape   Grosse Wonderful       False
11  Curtain Videotape   Grosse Wonderful        True
12  Curtain Videotape  Curtain Videotape       False
13    Airport Pollock    Airport Pollock       False
14     Cyclone Family     Cyclone Family       False
```

This can be used as a mask:

```
m = t.duplicated()
new_df = new_df.loc[m, ['Movie_title_x', 'Movie_title_y', 'Length']]
```

`new_df`:

```
        Movie_title_x     Movie_title_y  Length
3    Daddy Pittsburgh   Chamber Italian     117
6     Daisy Menagerie   Chamber Italian     117
7     Daisy Menagerie  Daddy Pittsburgh     117
11  Curtain Videotape  Grosse Wonderful     120
```

A one-liner:

```
new_df = df.merge(df, on='Length').loc[
    lambda t: pd.DataFrame(np.sort(t.filter(like='Movie_title_'), axis=1),
                           index=t.index).duplicated(),
    ['Movie_title_x', 'Movie_title_y', 'Length']
]
```